# vim-go syntax highlighting does not work consistently for custom types

Tags: go, vim, vim-plugin

I was able to install the `vim-go` plugin and configure my `vim` pretty much as shown in the tutorials for `golang` development. There is one thing though that didn't work for me, I am not sure if it was intended that way but it's pretty annoying for me and I would like to know if there is a way to fix it.

The problem is that the syntax highlighting doesn't work consistently when it comes to custom types as for the `type list []int` as seen in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u7fL.png) Ideally, the type should be highlighted for both these lines

```
func removeDuplicates(ld list) list {    // <- here                                                                     
    var lu list // <- here
```

this has been driving me crazy, please suggest something. Surprisingly in `main` it does highlight where the variable of the same type is provided with initial values.

Comment: vim-go's syntax highlighting is based on regular expressions; what you want requires an analysis of the source code, and this isn't really something vim-go supports. In the `var [..]` it knows because of the syntax. If you want really need fancy syntax highlighting then vim-go is probably not the right tool for you.

Comment: aah I see, @MartinTournoij, did you personally felt any difference in readability of large codebases? I am a novice in vim and relied heavily on IDEs, but now working with Docker and all I am starting myself to work with Vim.

Comment: I personally prefer a minimalistic approach to syntax highlighting, so I'm fine with vim-go (actually, I used  trimmed-down version). But tastes and preferences differ on this.